# Portability of #warning preprocessor directive

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, warnings, c-preprocessor, portability

I know that the #warning directive is not standard **C**/C++, but several compilers support it, including gcc/g++.  But for those that don't support it, will they silently ignore it or will it result in a compile failure?  In other words, can I safely use it in my project without breaking the build for compilers that don't support it?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It is likely that if a compiler doesn't support #warning, then it will issue an error. Unlike #pragma, there is no recommendation that the preprocessor ignore directives it doesn't understand.

Having said that, I've used compilers on various different (reasonably common) platforms and they have all supported #warning.

Comment: Apparently you never tried MS Visual Studio Professional 2015 ;-).

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: Certainly in 2008 I had not!

Answer (score 87):

It should be noted that MSVC uses the syntax:

```
#pragma message ( "your warning text here" )
```

The usual #warning syntax generates a fatal error

```
C1021: invalid preprocessor command 'warning'
```

so it is not portable to those compilers.

Comment: This is one of the rare cases, when MS does things in the right way.

Comment: Is MSVC syntax portable? I mean, would it properly generate a warning with other compilers?

Comment: Just ran a quick check using gcc-4.7.2. [$ gcc -c -Werror file.c] yields [file.c:10:9: note: #pragma message: Foo bar baz] So it produces a "note" that is not treated as a warning (i.e. It doesn't fail the build with -Werror enabled). But it appears parse correctly (as all #pragmas should be) so it is portable in that sense.

Comment: In MSVC 2008 `#pragma message` does not generate a warning too - it just outputs text to the Build Log. As result, f.i. it is not displayed in `Error List` window, nor increments the total number of warnings.

Comment: if you place 'warning' in the message then it still counts as a warning, e.g. #pragma message( "warning: foo" )

Comment: fwiw, this syntax works with openwatcom too. (yeah I bumped an old thread. People are going to google stuff like this forever)

Comment: @JustJeff, no worries, SO is a more enlightened place than those old, dust-covered forums where they like it that way (being covered with dust forever, once it has settled). 
Here you actually get a reward (a badge?) for extending an old post.

Comment: @doc It's _not_ the right way when it deviates from the _de facto_ norm.

Answer (score 3):

You are likely to get at least an unrecognized directive warning from compilers that don't recognize #warning, even if the code block is not included in your compilation.  That might or might not be treated as an error - the compiler could legitimately treat it as an error, but many would be more lax.

Are you aware of (can you name) a compiler other than GCC/G++ that provides #warning?
[*Edited:* Sun Solaris 10 (Sparc) and the Studio 11 C/C++ compilers both accept #warning.]

Answer (score 3):

When switching from mingw to visual studio, I added such lines to my global config header. (include it in stdafx.h)

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
//from https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html
//Instead of put such pragma in code:
//#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wformat"
//use:
//PRAGMA_GCC(diagnostic ignored "-Wformat")
#define DO_PRAGMA(x) _Pragma (#x)
#define PRAGMA_GCC(x) DO_PRAGMA(GCC #x)

#define PRAGMA_MESSAGE(x) DO_PRAGMA(message #x)
#define PRAGMA_WARNING(x) DO_PRAGMA(warning #x)
#endif //__GNUC__
#ifdef _MSC_VER
/*
#define PRAGMA_OPTIMIZE_OFF __pragma(optimize("", off))
// These two lines are equivalent
#pragma optimize("", off)
PRAGMA_OPTIMIZE_OFF
*/
#define PRAGMA_GCC(x)
// https://support2.microsoft.com/kb/155196?wa=wsignin1.0
#define __STR2__(x) #x
#define __STR1__(x) __STR2__(x)
#define __PRAGMA_LOC__ __FILE__ "("__STR1__(__LINE__)") "
#define PRAGMA_WARNING(x) __pragma(message(__PRAGMA_LOC__ ": warning: " #x))
#define PRAGMA_MESSAGE(x) __pragma(message(__PRAGMA_LOC__ ": message : " #x))

#endif

//#pragma message "message quoted"
//#pragma message message unquoted

//#warning warning unquoted
//#warning "warning quoted"

PRAGMA_MESSAGE(PRAGMA_MESSAGE unquoted)
PRAGMA_MESSAGE("PRAGMA_MESSAGE quoted")

#warning "#pragma warning quoted"

PRAGMA_WARNING(PRAGMA_WARNING unquoted)
PRAGMA_WARNING("PRAGMA_WARNING quoted")
```

Now I use PRAGMA_WARNING(this need to be fixed)

Sadly there is no `#pragma warning` in gcc, so it warns unspecified pragma.

I doubt that gcc will add `#pragma warning"` rather than microsoft adding `#warning`.

Comment: Currently boost supports BOOST_PRAGMA_MESSAGE

Comment: With GCC, this is : #pragma GCC warning "warning message"

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem once with a compiler for an Atmel processor. And it did generate preprocessor errors due to the unknown #warning token.

Unfortunately the solution seemed to be to convert the whole source tree to use the #pragma equivalent and accept that the build behavior was going to differ if using gcc.

Answer (score 0):

Actually most compilers that I know about ignore unknown #pragma directives, and output a warning message - so in the worst case, you'll still get a warning.

Comment: However, #warning isn't a #pragma.