# #warning in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

In gcc I can do compile-time warnings like this:

```
#if !defined(_SOME_FEATURE_)
   #warning _SOME_FEATURE_ not defined-- be careful!
#endif
```

But in Visual Studio this doesn't work.  Is there an alternative syntax for #warning?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

About the closest equivalent would be `#pragma message`, or possibly `#error` (the latter stops compilation, the former just prints out the specified error message).

Comment: `#pragma message` is not compatible with gcc though. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471935/user-warnings-on-msvc-and-gcc

Answer (score 14):

Use `#pragma message("Some message")`

Answer (score 8):

There is a good article here on how to achieve a similar effect to #warning in visual studio:

http://goodliffe.blogspot.co.uk/2009/07/c-how-to-say-warning-to-visual-studio-c.html

Edit: Here is the relevant section from the above link, however I do recommend reading the article.

```
#define STRINGIZE_HELPER(x) #x
#define STRINGIZE(x) STRINGIZE_HELPER(x)
#define WARNING(desc) message(__FILE__ "(" STRINGIZE(__LINE__) ") : Warning: " #desc)

// usage:
#pragma WARNING(FIXME: Code removed because...)
```

Comment: The question is for Visual Studio, and at 8 years old was for MSVC.

Comment: I thought it had been supposed to be cross-platform. I was wrong. You did not say so.

Answer (score 0):

`#pragma WEIRD_VALUES_HERE`

is the way I've always seen it done.  M$ probably has the pragmas on their site somewhere.

Comment: VS `#pragma` Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9x1s805%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Another thought is template style compile time asserts.  Boost has a whole selection of these if you are wanting to check compile time code errors.

Comment: The question asks for *warnings*.