# Clean way of generating custom warnings in cross platform C code?

Tags: c, build-process, cross-platform, warnings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [user warnings on msvc AND gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471935/user-warnings-on-msvc-and-gcc)

I am trying to come up with a relatively clean way of using the preprocessor to generate a custom warning message in C code that works for multiple compilers (MS VC, gcc, AIX, sun, etc).

I am mostly interested in warning about deprecated items, but also just for general use.

I know the Microsoft compiler supports "#pragma deprecated" and "#pragma message", and I've used "#warning" on gcc before. I know "#error" is in the C standard, but I just want a warning I don't want the compile process to stop.

I'm starting to get the feeling that every platform has a different way of doing this, but does anyone have any better ideas or tips?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471935/user-warnings-on-msvc-and-gcc covers MSVC and GCC.  It could probably be expanded to cover other compilers.

Comment: I agree that this is a duplicate, I didn't see the other question before and I think it covers what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @Matthew: Thanks for finding the original, and @bde, thanks for confirming that you found what you need.