# How do I flag a function as being deprecated in an iOS Objective-C header file?

Tags: objective-c, function, deprecated

How do I flag a function as being deprecated in an iOS Objective-C header file?

I'm guessing there's just some keyword I can stick after the function somewhere?

I would like for a compiler warning to be generated should anyone try and use the deprecated function, similar to the behavior seen in Apple's APIs.

Comment: Hey gs - good comment. I was actually thinking this just now!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Try appending an attribute to your method declaration:

```
- (void)fooBar __attribute__ ((deprecated));
```

Taken from [here](http://importantshock.wordpress.com/2006/12/27/objective-c-20/).

Comment: Looks like pretty ugly syntax - but if it works, it works! Thanks Tim.

Comment: you may _#define DEPRECATED _____attribute_____ ((deprecated))_

Comment: - (void)fooBar DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE; works for me. I don't think you need the #define as Denis suggested, it's already defined AFAIK

Comment: or you can simply use __deprecated

Comment: Huh. Appending `__deprecated` to a method declaration works too, and I have no idea why. Thanks for the suggestion, @ArtFeel - do you happen to know where that's defined?

Comment: this defined in [cdefs.h](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/bsd/sys/cdefs.h)

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Works like I expected - a `#define` to the attribute.

Comment: Awesome, just using __deprecated - works for @property too.  Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

Instead of `__attribute__((deprecated))`, you can use use the macros defined in `<cdefs.h>`:

```
- (void)fooBar __deprecated;
// Or better:
- (void)fooBar __deprecated_msg("Use barFoo instead.");
```

Or you can use the macros defined in `<AvailabilityMacros.h>`:

```
- (void)fooBar DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE;
// Or better:
- (void)fooBar DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE("Use barFoo instead.");
```

If you use Objective-C, it makes no difference as you are going to use a modern compiler, so you can go for Apple short syntax `__deprecated_msg()`. But if you use C for cross-platform, then `DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE()` uses the optimal availability definitions (for instance, it supports GCC3.1).

Answer (score 7):

Tim's answer will actually produce a compiler warning; the other versions are merely comments which have no effect w.r.t. the compiler.

If you look at /usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h, you'll see how Apple does this. That header uses `__attribute__((deprecated))` and `__attribute__((unavailable))` depending on whether the API is present but deprecated, or has actually been removed from the OS.

Answer (score 2):

From Apple's SFAuthorization.h:

```
/*!
DEPRECATED: Use obtainWithRight:flags:error:
@method permitWithRight:flags:
@abstract Call permitWithRight to gain a right to have
          access to a privilege operation.
@param rightName The name of an authorization right.
@param flags Authorization flags.
*/
- (OSStatus)permitWithRight:(AuthorizationString)rightName
                      flags:(AuthorizationFlags)flags;
```

If you're not using an automated documentation builder I'd say something like this is enough:

```
- (void)doSomething;           /* DEPRECATED */
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. If I use the 'permitWithRight' function in SFAuthorization, I get a compiler warning... Is there a way to add a deprecation flag to give compiler warnings?

Comment: You could use the preprocessor's command #warning, but it's not standard and likely to not work in all compilers. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171435/portability-of-warning-preprocessor-directive

Answer (score 2):

You could also follow the [HeaderDoc manual](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/HeaderDoc/intro/intro.html). Where this syntax is used:

```
/*!
 * @abstract Foo is good for bar.
 *
 * @deprecated in version 2.0
 */
```