# preventing init and forcing initWithOption

Tags: iphone, ios

I know you can have @private member variables but is there someway to prevent code from calling the default init: method of your class and forcing code that creates and uses your objects to only use another initializer such as initWithOptions:

I have had a flick through some Objective-C books and didn't immediately see anything.

I have seen the stack overflow topic suggesting to throw exception, or assert/abort/whatever in [how to prevent usage of other init methods other than my custom method in objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646440/how-to-prevent-usage-of-other-init-methods-other-than-my-custom-method-in-object)

and the use of the depreciated keyword
[How do I flag a function as being deprecated in an iPhone Objective C header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443599/how-do-i-flag-a-function-as-being-deprecated-in-an-iphone-objective-c-header-fil)

Both of these seem somewhat less than elegant solutions, there is really no language orientated elegant way to say doesNotImplmentSelector in Objective-C...?

I come from a C++ background and just kind of expected something like the ability to hide the default constructor...

R.

Answer (score 0):

I think the standard thing to do is to have an implementation of init which calls initWithOptions: with a default set of options.