# Change the method names of a subclass

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a subclass of `NSMutableArray` which in fact deals with a certain type of data i.e. say `Employee`. The problem is I don't like the inherented names of `addObject` `insertObject` and etc. and want to change them to something like `addEmployee` `insertEmployee`.

How should I deal with this?

Comment: Just to make sure: You _do_ know that `NSMutableArray` is not a normal class, but rather a class cluster's public abstract class, right? Thus it needs to be [handled](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-03-12-subclassing-class-clusters.html) [differently](http://blog.securemacprogramming.com/2010/05/on-type-safety-and-making-it-harder-to-write-buggy-code/).

Comment: Yeah I know of that; so indeed the current implementation is already using composition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not going to inherit the methods of the superclass then you should not use that superclass!

When you inherit it is a 'is a' relationship between the sub and super classes.  "Employer is a NSMutableArray" - no, that is not true and thus don't make Employer a subclass of NSMutableArray.  Additionally, in the future you might use a dictionary to store employees (like mapping 'name' -> 'employee') and then having the representation being inherited as an array simply won't work.

```
@interface Employer : NSObject {
  NSMutableArray *employees;
}

- (void) addEmployee: (Employee *) employee;
@end
```

Like such.  Now `addObject:` isn't workable on instances of Employee; only `addEmployee:` works.  Additionally, you'll only want to specialize methods like `filteredArrayWithPredicate:` eventually - so it won't be an advantage to inherit them.

Comment: If there are no better answers then I'll accept yours. The downside is that if I override `NSMutableArray` then I can get methods like `filteredArray..` for free just for overriding the few methods; but in this way I have to duplicate lots of methods..duh..

Comment: Edited with explanation on why inheritance if wrong; even if `__attribute__((unavailable,...)` is easy now.

Comment: Note that if you were really hell-bent on exposing all of NSArray's interface on the Employee object, you don't necessarily have to manually reimplement all of NSArray's methods, you can override Employee's `forwardInvocation:` to pass on any array methods to the NSArray ivar.

Answer (score 0):

You add a method `addEmployee:` and in that call `addObject:`. Similar for `insertObject:`

Comment: But that will still expose `addObject` to the client; and I'd like not to have that to happen :/

Comment: Right and you cannot avoid that using subclassing. You should have a look at the adapter pattern (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit `NSMutableArray` and add methods like `-addEmployee:` then add this in your .h file:

```
- (void)addObject:(id)anObject __attribute__((unavailable("Use -addEmployee:")));
```

This is a clang extension which will cause a complier error.

References:

[How do I flag a function as being deprecated in an iPhone Objective C header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443599/how-do-i-flag-a-function-as-being-deprecated-in-an-iphone-objective-c-header-fil)

http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#messages-on-deprecated-and-unavailable-attributes

Comment: That's a brilliant way that I've not thought of! I'll immediately give it a go

Comment: Oh, thats not clean, I think. inheritance adds one badness point, overriding a method another :)

Comment: Ineritance from an array class adds another thousand :)

Comment: I don't think inheritance is that bad, and I'm not overriding anything. I just tell the outside world some methods are not available.

Comment: I clarify, overriding every method adds responsibility that you did not have if you did not inherit. It adds code. Code will contain dead ends that you hope for will not get called.

Comment: Methods that will never get called as such are not very clean.

Comment: It seems a good and short answer to the problem but it does't work as well as I expected though...From my experiment I still get completion of `NSArray` methods.

Comment: Yes, you are actually pinpointing one ugly aspect there, yulan6248!

Comment: @yulan6248 When I call `-addObject:`, I get a complier error, saying `'addObject:' is unavailable: Use -addEmployee:`. What's your expectation?

Comment: @Anders Lindén Which method never get called?

Comment: Methods that you "turn off" by overriding them with "pukers" will hopefully never be called.

Comment: @leafduo I was hoping that the IDE is smart enough to understand these methods shouldn't be seen from the outside (like autocompletion popup etc.). But I was hoping too much

Comment: Its bad practice anyway, would be cool if the IDE could stop showing that methods for sure.

Comment: @yulan6248 IDE (Xcode) actually understands it, `-addObject:` will popup but with a red line through it.

Comment: @leafduo I was using AppCode and that might be the reason; but just as Anders has said, it's maybe the best practice to adhere to strict super/subclass relationships