# Should I customize an iPhone app for iPhone 6?

Tags: ios, ios8, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

Last year I have developed an iPhone app that works well in iPhone 5 and 4 (iOS 7), it was compiled in sdk 7.

Now I am updating the app to compile it under sdk 8, in order the app works well in iOS 8. My question is: should I customize my app for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus?. I am afraid if I don't do it Apple could reject my app.

Comment: You are right to be afraid of that. You _must_ run natively on iPhone 6 and 6 plus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some great comments on this question.

[How does an app with lower base sdk work?](http://http:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755473/how-does-an-app-with-lower-base-sdk-work//)

> "Apple never changes / deletes / renames classes or methods. They only
>   add new ones. If they don't want you to use it anymore, they mark it
>   as deprecated.
>
> This is a very important point. At compile-time, the compiler checks
>   if all classes and method signatures are available in the SDK your
>   building your app with.
>
> If that's the case, you can build and deploy your app. Because those
>   classes and methods will never be deleted from newer versions of the
>   framework, your app will run just fine."