# How to mark something in Qt as obsolete(deprecated)?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, deprecated, obsolete

Is there Q_OBSOLETE or Q_DEPRECATED in C++ with Qt 4.7?

Or is there a similar C++ macro or keyword?

Comment: What do you want such a macro or keyword to do?

Comment: To issue a warning if deprecated constructs are found in use. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation for better explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 2023:

Yes, the Qt is defined `QT_DEPRECATED` and `QT_DEPRECATED_X` macros for this purpose:

```cpp
QT_DEPRECATED void myOldFunc();
QT_DEPRECATED_X("use myNewFunc instead") void myOldFunc2();
```

difference is just the text message.
Also the C++14 presents `[[deprecated("text")]]` attribute as standard. It seems that this attribute is used under the hood if you use C++ 14+.

Comment: But what's the difference between Q_DECL_DEPRECATED (suggested by the top answer, dating back to 2012) and Q_DEPRECATED? By the way, are you sure it's Q_DEPRECATED? [In the docs](https://wiki.qt.io/Deprecation#Deprecating_an_API) I found the macros `QT_DEPRECATED` and `QT_DEPRECATED_X("message")` (notice: QT, not Q).

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica, take a look at the `qglobal.h` for differences between that two macros. Some other macros rely on the `QT_DEPRECATED`. Also, yeah! You right. I had a misspelling about the `Q_DEPRECATED`.

Answer (score 49):

If you use Q_DECL_DEPRECATED you should get the outcome you are looking for e.g.:

```
Q_DECL_DEPRECATED void foo();
```

Comment: I my case, I do use the attribute after the function name   void foo() Q_DECL_DEPRECATED;

Answer (score 1):

Just use the

```
#warning
```

directive

although is not C++ standard is quite unlikely you will encounter a compiler that does not support it ([see this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171435/portability-of-warning-preprocessor-directive)).

Comment: Windows / MSVC is a fairly common target with Qt, so I have to disagree with "quite unlikely."

Answer (score 1):

1. Pull the real function out of public scope.
2. Create another function with the same name in public scope.
3. Insert your warning/fail code in that function.
4. Call the original with the new.

Comment: Can't emit a compile time warning that way.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do something similiar yourself:

```
#ifdef Q_TREAT_OBSOLETE_AS_ERRORS
#define Q_OBSOLETE(X) \
        BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(false); \
        X

#else 
#define Q_OBSOLETE(X) X
#endif
```

This construction simply substitutes some deprecated code / part of code if there is no `Q_TREAT_OBSOLETE_AS_ERRORS` defined and generates compilation-time error otherwise.

Note that `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT` has no scope limitations, so does the `Q_OBSOLETE` macro.

*Probably this is not the best way to solve your problem and actually I'm not sure this is useful*.

You might just mark the code as `@obsolete` or simply point it out in the comments.

Comment: This doesn't work. This will cause compile errors if the deprecated code is **compiled**, whether or not that code is called from somewhere else.

Comment: @Ken Well, it's obviously that you don't have a way to check if some code chunk is actually being called. This static assertions thing simply helps drawing attention to the compilation of deprecated features. *Actually, all this Q_OBSOLETE stuff seems pretty unnecessary for me.*

Comment: he's asking (I think) because he's used to Java, which can annotate functions as deprecated, and give you a compiler warning when you try to use them.

Answer (score -4):

By "deprecated constructs", you really mean "deprecated member functions". You're asking for a compile-time warning to draw your attention to the call site of any deprecated function.

This isn't possible in any reasonable way in standard C++, and I don't see any attributes in G++ that would support this either. Qt can't really add a feature like that if the compiler doesn't have some support for it already.

However, Microsoft Visual C++ supports an [`__declspec(deprecated)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/044swk7y%28VS.80%29.aspx) extension, and I would imagine it's possible to write a compiler plugin for G++ 4.5 that adds a similar feature.

Comment: It seems I missed `__attribute__((deprecated))` in G++.

Comment: By the way in c++14 and so there's the `[[deprecated]]` keyword that you can add to some functions http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes