# How to generate compile time errors?

Tags: c++

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
   void f(int*p = nullptr)
    {
    if (!p)
{
//HERE I WOULD LIKE TO HAVE AN MSG THAT WOULD BE DISPLAYED DURING COMPILATION AS A WARNING POSSIBLY
}
    }
```

Comment: You want a warning at compile time, depening on what's happening at runtime? In general that's not possible. Perhaps you want something slightly different that we can actually help with? Please elaborate on the problem you are trying to solve :)

Comment: Why would the function provide an illegal default argument `nullptr`? That's rather pointless, isn't it? :)

Comment: @FredOverflow - it isn't pointles if you look at this from the point of view that depending on policy this function is run with pointer passed or with nullptr ;)

Comment: @There:  You still haven't answered the fundamental question:  How can you generate a *compiler* error for something that happens at *runtime*?

Comment: And if it didn't have a default parameter, you would get a compiler error if you tried to call it without arguments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct answer is:  What you're trying to do won't ever work.

Answer (score 20):

To generate a compile time warning based on a runtime check, simply create a file called "warning.c" that contains an unused variable declaration. You can then generate warnings like that:

```
void f(int *p = nullptr) {
    if (!p) {
        system("gcc -Wall warning.c");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's pretty funny, and answers the question!

Comment: `system("cat int c; > /tmp/warning.c && gcc -Wall /tmp/warning.c && rm /tmp/warning.c");` - might as well supply it :)

Answer (score 5):

Most, [if not all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171435/portability-of-warning-preprocessor-directive), compilers support the [`#error`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fwar_directive.htm) and [`#warning`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fwar_directive.htm) preprocessor directives.

Microsoft's compiler, though, uses [`#pragma message()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7dkzch2%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) instead of `#warning`.

Comment: I do use Visual Studio and I've tried to use #pragma message but for bizzare reasons doesn't work for me.

Comment: @There `#pragma message("blah")` has worked for me for >10 years. If it doesn't work for you, you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Google `#if` `#endif` and `#error` preprocessor directives. It won't be possible to generate compile error based on the value of a variable that is not available at compile time, so forget about it. Use `assert()`.