# How to WRITE compile time warning for user

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, g++

I would like to write a Pragma warning **in GNU G++** for every user that compile my codes.

How can i do this?
I am using GNU G++ compiler.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

MSVC and newer GCCs support:

```
#pragma message ( "your warning text here" )
```

In GCC the other syntax is  also commonly used:

```
#warning "you warning text here"
```

See also question: [Portability of #warning preprocessor directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171435/portability-of-warning-preprocessor-directive) and **[GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html#Diagnostic-Pragmas)**

Comment: IIRC gcc warns that `#warning` is a gcc extension. So you'll get two warnings instead of one.

Comment: @bitmask The gcc documentation says that the warning can be disabled: `-Wno-cpp`