# How can I deprecate a C++ header?

Tags: c++, deprecated

I would like to deprecate a C++ header so that if someone includes it in their code, the compiler issues a warning.

I know that I can deprecate individual symbols, for example, using C++14 `[[deprecated]]`, but is there a similar thing for headers? Maybe some clever trick?

Note that I want the compiler to issue a warning even if the user doesn't use anything from the header.

Comment: `#warning Do not disturb the giant.`

Comment: Worth noting that `#warning` technically [isn't portable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/171435/3282436).

Comment: Yeah, my bad, I should have specified that I am looking for a solution for the MSVC, GCC and Clang compilers. It doesn't have to be the same solution but I would like to have something for each compiler. So far it seems that `#warning` doesn't work for MSVC.

Comment: Do you want a warning at max? Because there is `#error`.

Comment: Not just "technically" unportable. By that, I mean, it's not merely an abstract concern only of interest to purists and dogmatists. MSVC will *error* if your code includes `#warning`, which makes it not a valid choice in most circumstances. Use a `#pragma` instead; that's supported much more widely and won't ever result in an error per the standard. Something like [Hedley](https://nemequ.github.io/hedley/) wraps this up for you in a compiler-agnostic public interface.

Comment: Strongly related: [Is there a way to deprecate a namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22806878/is-there-a-way-to-deprecate-a-namespace) and [C++ mark as deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295120/c-mark-as-deprecated)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Here is a possible (albeit perhaps not too elegant) solution.

Insert in the header a code like that

```
// badheader.hpp
namespace {
[[deprecated("This header is deprecated")]]
constexpr static int badheader_hpp_is_deprecated = 0;
constexpr static int please_dont_use_badheader_hpp = badheader_hpp_is_deprecated;
}
```

This creates a deprecated variable `badheader_hpp_is_deprecated`. The initialization of `please_dont_use_badheader_hpp` triggers the deprecated warning. Notice that I put both variables inside an anonymous namespace, to avoid possible name conflicts.
Still, as noted in the comment, a name clash *could* still happen if, in the same compilation unit, a variable with the same name is declared inside the anonymous namespace. For this reason, as suggested in the comments, variables in the code above have a descriptive name, rendering name clash high improbable.

Comment: Make it even more improbably by stashing the anonymous namespace inside the namespace where all the headers symbols are located.

Answer (score 21):

A non-standard, but fairly portable solution:

```
#pragma message("Header `foo.h` is deprecated!")
```

This is accepted by GCC, Clang, and MSVC. GCC and Clang also accept the form without `( )`.

This is not necessarily a "warning", but should be good enough.

Answer (score 16):

I suggest surrounding your namespace with a namespace with the same name and `using` it from within the enclosing namespace.

```
#pragma once

namespace your_namespace {
    namespace [[deprecated]] your_namespace {
        // old stuff
    }
    using namespace your_namespace;
}
```

This shouldn't taint your global namespace with anything from `your_namespace` and still give the warning if you include the header. The old stuff will still be accessible via `your_namespace::` as before.

Since this is an ABI breaking change, I recommend stepping the major version of the library too if you didn't already when deprecating the header.

Comment: That is an ABI-breaking change though. Which isn't that good an idea especially if the aim is gradually phasing out cruft.

Comment: @Deduplicator True to a degree. The breakage hits once (when the header becomes deprecated) and it hits when you decide to upgrade to this new version of the library. Recompiling your code wouldn't be a big ask.

Comment: Yes. If your code is the executable, you have control over upgrading the dependency, and there are no 3rd party libraries interacting with that code. Otherwise, it gets hairy.

Comment: Deduplicator Very good point. I added a recommendation to deal with it.

Answer (score 12):

This one is shamelessly copied from the [range-v3 library](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/1120609c7cb5dee9d2d216c579e935475cc39c4e/include/range/v3/detail/config.hpp#L516):

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#define RANGES_PRAGMA(X) _Pragma(#X)
#define RANGES_DEPRECATED_HEADER(MSG) RANGES_PRAGMA(GCC warning MSG)
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
#define RANGES_STRINGIZE_(MSG) #MSG
#define RANGES_STRINGIZE(MSG) RANGES_STRINGIZE_(MSG)
#define RANGES_DEPRECATED_HEADER(MSG) \
    __pragma(message(__FILE__ "(" RANGES_STRINGIZE(__LINE__) ") : Warning: " MSG))
#endif

RANGES_DEPRECATED_HEADER("Yikes! A deprecated header!")
```

Try it with [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/d38Kjeda7).

Answer (score 6):

If your header has a namespace, you could use the `[[deprecated]]` on it I guess? But this doesn't work on anonymous namespaces. And the user has to use something from the headspace for it to work.

If you can put the header in a namespace, then all you have to do is have a `using` statement that will trigger the warning. This could be also a good idea to isolate those functions, and making sure users have more difficulty using them if that's an objective.

```
namespace [[deprecated]] N {
    struct S {

    };
}

using N::S;
```

But if you can't afford the namespace, depending on the number of elements, you probably don't want to use a `using` on all of them.
Maybe that could be a case for legitimately having a `using namespace N;`, but I'm not sure.

After some research, you could use `#pragma message "Message"` to possibly also achieve what you seem to be wanting. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3826876/3313819)

[godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:9,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:9,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:9,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:9),source:%27namespace+%5B%5Bdeprecated%5D%5D+N+%7B%0A++++struct+S+%7B%0A%0A++++%7D%3B%0A%0A++++void+toto()+%7B%0A%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Ausing+N::S%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:52.48925837455786,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_assertions_trunk,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%271%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-pthread++-Wall+-O3+++-std%3Dc%2B%2B17%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+(assertions+trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:47.51074162544215,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+(assertions+trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:47.51074162544215,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)