# Example of a conditionally-supported-directive

Tags: c++, c++17, preprocessor-directive

Paragraph 1 of [Preprocessing directives](http://eel.is/c++draft/cpp) in the Standard defines the grammar production *conditionally-supported-directive*. And paragraph [2](http://eel.is/c++draft/cpp#2) says the following about this item:

> A conditionally-supported-directive is conditionally-supported with
>   implementation-defined semantics.

I'd like to have an example, if possible, of this *conditionally-supported-directive*.

Comment: I think "conditionally supported" here just means that it is supported by the implementation with the conditions that are placed on it by the implementation.

Comment: e.g. `#warning`

Comment: @cpplearner Yes, it appears gcc [supports #warning](http://stackoverflow.com/q/171435/1042389)